# How to create complicated tables (multiple nested columns and rows)

Tags: tables

I have an image of a table that I want to replicate but I can't figure out how to do the multiple rows part (see left side of column) and the multiple columns part (see right side).

Is there a general way to do this? How do you go about creating such tables? The numbers are irrelevant, I'm looking for a piece of code that I can easily extend as necessary (add more rows/colums).

[image: Complicated table]

**Edit:**

Thanks to @leandriis, the following works well:

```
\begin{tabular}{c|c|cccccc}
%\toprule
Metric & Dataset & 
%\multicolumn{6}{c}{SGAN (Ours)}\\ \cmidrule{3-8} & &
\makecell[b]{20V-20 \\ (pretrained)} & \makecell[b]{20VP-20 \\ (pretrained)} & \makecell[b]{20VP-20 \\ (retrained)} & \makecell[b]{Mean \\ Pooling} & \makecell[b]{Random \\ Pooling} & \makecell[b]{Gumble \\ Pooling}\\
\midrule
 & ETH & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
 & ETH & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
 ADE & ETH & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
 & ETH & 3  & 3 & 3\\
  & ETH & 3 & 3 & 3 \\ 
  AVG & & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
  \midrule\midrule
 & ETH & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
 & ETH & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
 ADE  & ETH & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
 & ETH & 3  & 3 & 3\\
  & ETH & 3 & 3 & 3 \\ 
  AVG & & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
\bottomrule\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```

[image: Resulting table]

Comment: It is not very hard to do. What have you tried?

Comment: You might be interested in `\multicolumn` and `\multirow`.

Comment: Do you need a reproduction of the exact format, or do you prefer a more classic, and nicer, layout?

Comment: @Sveinung I'm unfamiliar with the options there are (classic, nicer, ??), For now, I'm fine with learning how to create tables with whatever is easier (less code, readable code).

Comment: My question was if you needed an exact reproduction of you example. Nicer means a classic, formal book style table, without vertical rules, and more space between rows.

Comment: @Sveinung Where can I learn how to create such nicer tables?

Comment: Here at stackexchange. Search on "booktabs". I will give you an example, if not Bernhard or leandriis does it befor me (or Mico)

Comment: ```\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c} \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Metric}} &\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Dataset}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Linear}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{LSTM}}& \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{S-LSTM}}& \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{SGAN (Ours)}}\\\&&&&& 1V-I&1V-20&20V20&20VP-20\\\\\hline\hline multirow{5}{*}{\textbf{ADE}}& \textbf{ETH} & ...& 061 / \textbf{0.81} & \textbf{0.60} / 0.87 \\ & \textbf{HOTEL} & ... & 0.52 / 0.67 \\\``` This is a code for a simple format without siunitx package and booktabs etc... You just need to complete it and to ad `multirow` package in your preamble.

Comment: You do not need `makecell` to typeset the first headers. Just use two rows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a short code, that might serve as a place to start from. I have included some `\multicolumn` an `\multirow` commands in order to get the alignment that was mentioned in the question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Metric}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Dataset}} & 
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{SGAN (Ours)}}\\
& & 1V-1 & 1V-20 & 20V-20\\
\hline \hline
 & \textbf{ETH} & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
 & \textbf{ETH} & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
ADE  & \textbf{ETH} & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
 & \textbf{ETH} & 3  & 3 & 3\\
  & \textbf{ETH} & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
\hline
\textbf{AVG} & & & & \\
\hline\hline
 & \textbf{ETH} & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
 & \textbf{ETH} & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
ADE  & \textbf{ETH} & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
 & \textbf{ETH} & 3  & 3 & 3\\
  & \textbf{ETH} & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
\hline
\textbf{AVG} & & & & 
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Here is also a suggestion on how to use the `booktabs` package in order to create a table that has no vertical and just a few horizontal lines with some additional white space around them. I'd also suggest to not use bold for the column headers and the contents of the first/second column:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ccccc}
\toprule
Metric & Dataset & 
\multicolumn{3}{c}{SGAN (Ours)}\\ \cmidrule{3-5}
& & 1V-1 & 1V-20 & 20V-20\\
\midrule
ADE & ETH & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
 & ETH & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
  & ETH & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
 & ETH & 3  & 3 & 3\\
  & ETH & 3 & 3 & 3 \\ 
  AVG & & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
  \midrule
ADE & ETH & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
 & ETH & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
  & ETH & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
 & ETH & 3  & 3 & 3\\
  & ETH & 3 & 3 & 3 \\ 
  AVG & & 3 & 3 & 3 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Here is a comparison of both tables side by side:

[image]

For an improved alignment of the numbers in column 3-9 I'd suggest tue usage of the `siunitx` package.

Comment: Is there a reason you left out lines between for example "Metric" and "Dataset" or "ADE and "AVG"?

Comment: @AnnaVopureta: Do you refer to the vertical lines that I completely removed in my second example? If so, this is due to the "more classic, and nicer, layout" that Sveinung already mentioned/explained in [their comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/500838/how-to-create-complicated-tables-multiple-nested-columns-and-rows/500842#comment1264999_500838).

Comment: Yes, I mean the vertical lines from the second example. I think it would look good to at least add vertical lines to separate table structure and the data (maybe I'm wrong let's see). How can I add such vertical lines?

Comment: @AnnaVopureta: Personally, I don't agree that vertical lines would be useful in this table. But if you prefer to have them, you can use `|` inbetween the column specifiers (`\begin{tabular}{cc}` without line and `\begin{tabular}{c|c}`with vertical line)  just as in the first example. Please also note, that `booktabs` lines are incompatible with vertical lines, so it might be better to stay with the first example code (usage of `\hline`) then.

Comment: `\begin{tabular}{c|c}` works on the second example too thanks! Another question, is there a reason why you didn't center "ADE" and "ADE" (under metrics) in the second example? How can I center them to see how it looks?

Comment: @AnnaVopureta: Please have a closer look at the intersections of the horizontal and vertical lines if you add `|` to the second example. You will notice that there is  a small white space in the vertical lines. This is due to the booktabs rules being incompatible with vertical lines.

Comment: Regarding the centered contents of the first column: Personally, I don't think vertically centering them adds to the readability of the table, but if you prefer this, replace `ADE` by `\multirow{5}{=}{ADE}`.

Comment: Unfortunately, `\multirow{5}{=}{ADE}`causes "ADE" not only to be centered, but it also shifts it to the right a bit (then the table looks odd because "ADE is not vertically alligned with the rest)

Comment: @AnnaVopureta: Sorry for the typo, I meant `\multirow{5}{*}{ADE}`. This should work. Alternatively,  you can also go without `multirow` if you move the text "ADE"  two rows down (to the third row of the respective block of five rows) as I have done in the first example code.

Comment: Huh, when I try to extend the table (add more rows) the table goes off the page instead of being resized to fit the page.

Comment: @AnnaVopureta: Tables don't automatically resize to fit into the textwidth. You could do one of the following: a) reduce the font size b) decrease teh margins c) decrease the horizontal white space between columns... ore ideas can be found for example here: [My table doesn't fit; what are my options?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/332902/134144) If you have problems implementing the solutions presented there, please ask a new question and include a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) there that allows others to easily reproduce teh output you get.

Comment: At a second glance I read that you added more rows (not columns as I initially thought). In that case, you might also be interested in the `longtable` package that allows long table s to be split over multiple pages.

Comment: I meant columns, not rows sorry. I ended up using `\usepackage{makecell}` to shorten the column names, now everything fits.

Answer (score 4):

Here is your tabular typeset approximately how I would have done in my documents. I have one grade smaller letters in the heading, and italic instead of bold to emphasise headings and numbers. this is based on the recommendation in a text book for the typography study in Norway. I increased the margins so the tabular fits between the margin.

In the preamble, I have used three commands to change the tabular’s spacing:

```
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
```

The first command moves the cell content a little bit down. The second increases the spacing between rows (creates some air). The third command decreases the spacing between columns.

I have removed all vertical rules and used a heavier rule and added space instead of double `\hline`s; all according to recommendations in the [booktabs](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) manual. That package is used to typeset all rules, so you have suitable distance between rules and cell content. I have also used the [array](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package to have more flexible table commands.

*NB!* The [booktabs manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) is a must read if you want to typeset nice tabulars.

As you also will see, I use two right align column to typeset the numbers. Since all cells have the same number of decimals, you can use simple `r`-columns in combination with an array-trick to typeset `1.21 / 2.35`. To typeset the slash between each pair of numbers, I use `r@{\,/\,}r`, which removes all space between the two columns and replaces it with two tiny spaces (`\,`) and the slash in between.

In the headings, I have merged two columns using `multicolumn`. For additional tips on how to typeset a tabular, I checked a text book used from the mid-fifties  for educating typographers in Norway. I have updated my example to be more in:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{makecell, array, booktabs, multirow, caption}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4.5pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!t]
\caption{Tabular with lots of columns}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{\kern0.1em}cl r@{\kern0.05em/\kern0.05em}r r@{\kern0.05em/\kern0.05em}r r@{\kern0.05em/\kern0.05em}r r@{\kern0.05em/\kern0.05em}r r@{\kern0.05em/\kern0.05em}r r@{\kern0.05em/\kern0.05em}r r@{\kern0.05em/\kern0.05em}r@{\kern0.1em}}
\toprule    
\multirow{2}{*}[-0.75ex]{\small{Metric}} & \multirow{2}{*}[-0.75ex]{\small{Dataset}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}[-0.75ex]{\small{Linear}}}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}[-0.75ex]{\small{LSTM}}}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}[-0.75ex]{\small{S-LSTM}}}&\multicolumn{8}{c@{}}{\small{SGAN (Ours)}}    \\\cmidrule(l){9-16}
\multicolumn{8}{l}{}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\small{1V-1}}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\small{1V-20}}&\multicolumn{2}{c}{\small{20V-20}}&\multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{\small{20VP-20}}    \\\midrule
&ETC&0.84&1.33&0.70&1.09&0.73&1.09&0.79&1.13&0.75&1.03&0.61&\emph{0.81}&\emph{0.60}&0.87 \\
&HOTEL&\emph{0.35}&\emph{0.39}&0.55&0.86&0.49&079&0.71&1.01&0.63&0.90&0.48&0.72&0.52&0.67  \\
ADE&UNIV&0.56&0.82&0.36&0.61&0.41&0.67&0.37&0.60&0.36&0.58&\emph{0.36}&\emph{0.60}&0.44&0.76  \\
&ZARA1&0.41&0.62&0.25&0.41&0.27&0.47&0.25&0.42&0.23&0.38&\emph{0.21}&\emph{0.34}&0.22&0.35  \\
&ZARA2&0.53&0.77&0.31&0.52&0.33&0.56&0.32&0.52&0.29&0.47&\emph{0.27}&0.42&0.29&\emph{0.42}  \\\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{\emph{AVG}}&&0.54&0.79&0.43&0.70&0.45&0.72&0.49&0.74&0.45&0.67&\emph{0.39}&\emph{0.58}&0.41&0.61 \\\bottomrule\addlinespace[1ex]
&ETC&1.60&2.94&1.45&2.41&1.48&2.35&1.61&2.21&1.52&2.02&1.22&\emph{1.52}&\emph{1.19}&1.62 \\
&HOTEL&\emph{0.60}&\emph{0.72}&1.17&.1.91&1.01&1.76&1.44&2.18&1.32&1.97&0.95&1.61&1.02&1.37 \\
FDE&UNIV&1.01&1.59&0.77&1.31&0.84&1.40&0.75&1.28&\emph{0.73}&\emph{1.22}&0.75&1.26&0.84&1.52 \\
&ZARA1&0.74&1.21&0.53&0.88&0.56&1.00&0.53&0.91&0.48&0.84&\emph{0.42}&0.69&0.43&\emph{0.68}  \\
&ZARA2&0.95&1.48&0.65&1.11&0.70&1.17&0.66&1.11&0.61&1.01&\emph{0.54}&\emph{0.84}&0.58&0.84  \\\midrule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{\emph{AVG}}&&0.98&1.59&0.91&1.52&0.91&1.54&1.00&1.54&0.93&1.41&\emph{0.78}&\emph{1.18}&0.81&1.21  \\\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```